# Calculate inside \setlength

Tags: pgfmath, calc

I'm subdividing my page in a number of sections and I want to calculate the width of each section depending of the number.

```
\newlength{\basewidth}
\setlength{\basewidth}{\linewidth/5.5}
```

The `\basewidth` should be `1/5.5` of the `\linewidth` because there are 5 sections that are equally wide and one that should have half the width of the other ones. (5 + 0.5 = 5.5)

I do use the `calc` package!

When printing `\the\linewidth` I get 816.59412 pt which seems correct. The calculation `\linewidth/5.5` is not accepted and the equivalent `0.181818\linewidth` returns 62.72919 which is not correct, given that the result should be 148.471658...

How am I supposed to calculate with lengths if this is obviously wrong?

---

#### MWE

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document setup
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Page layout
\usepackage[headheight = 11ex, margin = .5cm, top = 3.2cm, nofoot, showframe = true]{geometry}

% Logic and Tools
\usepackage{calc}


% Setup of lengths
\newlength{\basewidth}
\setlength{\basewidth}{2\columnwidth/11}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \centering
    Linewidth: \the\columnwidth\\
    Base: \the\basewidth\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\basewidth}{0.18182\linewidth}` Or, with `calc`, `\setlength{\basewidth}{2\linewidth/11}` Only integers are accepted as divisors.

Comment: As already said, `\setlength{\basewidth}{0.18182\linewidth}` returns 62.72919. The same is true for `\setlength{\basewidth}{2\linewidth/11}`

Comment: In which case do you get 816pt for the line width? That's 28.7cm! By the way, you want `\columnwidth` rather than `\linewidth` that's not fixed across the document.

Comment: It's a DinA4 paper in landscape with .5cm margins.

Comment: I get 816.59412 for the line width, 148.47618 with the multiplying factor and 148.47165 with 2/11 (the difference is expected). Please, make a minimal example.

Comment: I also get this correct result in an MWE. I'm currently trying to reproduce the wrong output.

Comment: @egreg I added an MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\linewidth` is set in `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[headheight = 11ex, margin = .5cm, top = 3.2cm, nofoot]{geometry}

\typeout{\string\linewidth=\the\linewidth}
\typeout{2\string\linewidth/11=\the\dimexpr2\linewidth/11\relax}

\begin{document}

\typeout{After \string\begin{document}:}
\typeout{\string\linewidth=\the\linewidth}
\typeout{2\string\linewidth/11=\the\dimexpr2\linewidth/11\relax}

\end{document}
```

Result (`.log` file):

> ```
> \linewidth=345.0pt
> 2\linewidth/11=62.72728pt
> [...]
> After \begin{document}:
> \linewidth=816.59412pt
> 2\linewidth/11=148.47166pt
> ```

The code of `\begin{document}` contains:

```
\columnwidth\textwidth
[...]
\hsize\columnwidth
\linewidth\hsize
```

Thus, you can use `\textwidth` in the preamble instead of `\columnwidth` or `\linewidth`.